# How to use onDoubleClick on MUI TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to select the text in the input field whenever the user double clicks the input field, I have made a function for this which is,

```
export const selectText = (
  event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement, MouseEvent>
): void => {
  event.currentTarget.select();
};
```

But how to I use it on mui Text Field, there are no props for `onDoubleClick` in mui documentation. I I simply send a prop

```
<TextField
  id={id}
  name={name}
  value={value}
  onDoubleClick={selectText}
/>
```

I get this error,

[image]

(I am trying to select numbers on double click not text.)

Comment: Isn't selecting the text on double click the default behaviour of inputs?  Just type some text (inside doc example inputs)[https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#main-content], double click on it and the text will be selected

Comment: @Dmitriif It is, but it does not work for input types which are numbers, I am trying to select numbers on double click.

Comment: It still should work without extra actions, I've created a [demo with MUI TextField and native number input](https://codesandbox.io/s/number-inputs-leyyx?file=/demo.tsx) to show it

Comment: @Dmitriif yes it does thanks, but if I click on number, if I click somewhere else on the input field, it won't select. It would be great if you can help me with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach it in `inputProps` to the native `input` element (that is rendered inside the `TextField`).

```
<TextField
    id={id}
    name={name}
    value={value}
    inputProps={{
        onDoubleClick: selectText
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me @ColdAtNight

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when the user double click:

```
<TextField onDoubleClick={() => console.log('double click')} />
```

If you only want double click without having to listen to the single click event:

```
<TextField onClick={(e) => e.detail === 2 && console.log('double click only')} />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]